# How to define layout in a PopupWindow from an xml file, when PopupWindow method is called from a separate class

Tags: android, xml, popupwindow

I'd like to be able to define layout in a PopupWindow from an xml file when the PopupWindow method is called from a separate class. Below code works as needed EXCEPT that layout is pulled from the java file and not the xml file.I do not know how to properly access xml layout and implement in the PopupWindow in this situation, or if this is possible. Advice and specific suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

**showPopup.java**

```
public class showPopup {
Context ctx;
Button btnDismiss;

public showPopup(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;     
}

public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container) {
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);   
    btnDismiss = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btndismissxml);
}

public void goJoe(View parent){ 
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(ctx);

    btnDismiss = new Button (ctx);
    btnDismiss.setText("Text is from showPopup.java");

    popup.setContentView(btnDismiss);
    popup.setWidth(400);
    popup.setHeight(580);
    popup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 10, 10);        

    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popup.dismiss();    
        }
    });
  }
}
```

**Tab3Fragment.java**

```
public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
Button btnPopup;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup containerGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_fragment, containerGroup, false);   
    btnPopup = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPopupxml);
    btnPopup.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}
//@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v) {
    btnPopup = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPopupxml);
    btnPopup.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View parent) {
    new showPopup(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).goJoe(parent); 
  }
}
```

**popup_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout">

<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/btndismissxml"
    android:text="Text is from popup_layout.xml"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update (1835, Dec-11):**
This is a draft popup. There will be several of these servicing user editable dropdown fields in the application.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `showPopup` like this

```
public class showPopup {
Context ctx;
Button btnDismiss, btnSaveRecord, btnLastRecord;
EditText edSpeciesLookup,edSpeciesLookupRowid;
DBAdapter msdb;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public showPopup(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx; 
    msdb = new DBAdapter(ctx,"gfda", null);     
    db = msdb.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void goJoe(View parent){ 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popUpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null, false);
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, 400,
                    580, true);         
    popup.setContentView(popUpView);
    btnDismiss = (Button) popUpView.
                    findViewById(R.id.btndismissxml);
    edSpeciesLookup = (EditText) popUpView.
                    findViewById(R.id.editspecieslookupxml);
    edSpeciesLookupRowid = (EditText) popUpView.
                    findViewById(R.id.editspecieslookuprowidxml);
    popup.showAtLocation(parent, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 10, 10);        

    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popup.dismiss();    
        }
    });

    btnSaveRecord = (Button) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveRecordxml);
    btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {//SAVE
            String szSpecies = edSpeciesLookup.getText().toString();
        if(szSpecies.matches("")){//checks to see if species field is empty...
            ///nothing happens...
        }else{db.execSQL("INSERT INTO speciesLookupDb (species) VALUES ('"+szSpecies+"')");
            resetForm();
        }
    }
    });

    btnLastRecord=(Button)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.btnLastRecordxml);
    btnLastRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM speciesLookupDb WHERE _id = (SELECT MAX(_id) FROM speciesLookupDb)",null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()){////a record exists (table is not blank)           
                edSpeciesLookupRowid.setText(c.getString(0));
                edSpeciesLookup.setText(c.getString(1));            
            }else{//no record here...table is blank.        
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

If you want to dismiss `popup` on touching anywhere in screen then you have to add these lines after `setContentView` of popup and before `showAtLocation`

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.any_drawable);
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                    bitmap));
popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popup.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: u haven't initialize those `EditText` thats why get *NPE* chk the edit and replace those ids with proper ids.

Comment: u have to **initialize** all field which u want to use in *Java* code otherwise u'll get *NPE*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66712/discussion-between-kaushik-and-38859).

Comment: ...@NNE would you be interested in another question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556820/refreshing-parent-fragment-on-popupwindow-dismiss

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

From API docs, A fragment that displays a dialog window, floating on top of its activity's window. This fragment contains a Dialog object, which it displays as appropriate based on the fragment's state. Control of the dialog (deciding when to show, hide, dismiss it) should be done through the API here, not with direct calls on the dialog.

Implementations should override this class and implement onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) to supply the content of the dialog. Alternatively, they can override onCreateDialog(Bundle) to create an entirely custom dialog, such as an AlertDialog, with its own content.

1.Create your custom popup layout.

2.Create custom dialog fragment.

3.Create interface for button click.

4.Call it on your fragment.

**1.Create your custom popup layout.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/app_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="TITLE"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popupMsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/app_title"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/navBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/popupMsg"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="OK" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**2.Create custom dialog fragment.**

```
import android.app.Dialog;

import android.app.DialogFragment;

.....

public class CustomAlert extends DialogFragment {

public OnSubmitListener mListener;
Context context;
String Title = "";
String content = "";

public CustomAlert (Context context, String title, String message) {
    this.context = context;
    this.Title = title;
    this.content = message;

  }

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_layout);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
    TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.app_title);
    TextView msg = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popupMsg);
    Button btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.navBtn);
    title.setText(Title);
    msg.setText(content);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.setOnAlert(content);
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return dialog;
  }
  }
```

**3.Create interface for button click.**

```
public interface OnSubmitListener{

  void setOnAlert(String arg);

 }
```

**4.Implement it on your fragment.**

```
  public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnSubmitListener{
  Button btnPopup;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup containerGroup, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {   

     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_fragment, containerGroup, false);   
     btnPopup = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPopupxml);
    
     return v;
   }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        btnPopup.setOnClickListener(getActivity());
  }
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    ShowDialog("Title", "Sample content");
   }


  private void ShowDialog(String title, String msg) {
    CustomAlert fragment1 = new CustomAlert (
            getActivity(), title, msg);
    fragment1.mListener = this;
    fragment1.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
  }

    @Override
    public void setOnAlert(String arg) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Button Clicked:"+arg,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Silambarasan for your thoughtful answer. My impression of Dialog boxes is that they are fairly structured and might not work out as mini database browsers that is my intention. I've included a screenshot of a draft popup at the bottom of my question. Thank you again for your time and answer. Best regards.