# How to do popup menus on button clicked with labeled icons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I am trying to achieve this as per guideline:
[image]

Basically I wanted something like this:

[image]

I wanted to make this appear to a popup just like the one from the docs.

When the user click 'views', a custom view will appear showing more options. I am creating a custom layout for `PopupWindow` but its not giving me the result I want. I am creating a simple color chooser where it allows user to choose 8 colors only. I tried inflating a layout containing a `RecyclerView` but it looked like this:

[image]

I know this is impossible, but does anyone able to achieve what "Google" is advertising on their guides? I believe it is impossible and yet many apps are able to do it.

Here is my code on how I instantiated my popup:

```
private void showChooseColorPopup()
{
    /*
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, mBottomMenuPanelLinearLayout);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_note_color, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
    */

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_popup_menu_note_color , null);

    NoteColorSelectionAdapter adapter = new NoteColorSelectionAdapter(this, NotifireID.colors);
    adapter.setOnColorSelected(this);

    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this , 3);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_popup_menu_note_color);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    // TODO Use Dialog instead

    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_white));

    int location[] = new int[2];
    mColorButton.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(mColorButton, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, location[0] , location[1] - mColorButton.getHeight());
    // popupWindow.show(mColorButton);
}
```

Here is my adapter for the GridView:

```
package com.neonwarge.android.notifire.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.neonwarge.android.notifire.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NoteColorSelectionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteColorSelectionAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private final static int COUNT = 8;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mColors;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnColorSelected mOnColorSelected;

    public interface OnColorSelected
    {
        public void onColorSelected(View v, int position, int color);
    }

    public NoteColorSelectionAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<Integer> noteColors)
    {
        mColors = noteColors;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_popup_menu_note_color, parent, false);

        NoteColorSelectionAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new NoteColorSelectionAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        int selectedColor = mColors.get(position);
        final int p = position; final int color = selectedColor;

        switch(selectedColor)
        {
            case R.color.yellow:
                holder.mColorImageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_yellow));
                break;

            case R.color.orange:
                holder.mColorImageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_orange));
                break;

            case R.color.purple:
                holder.mColorImageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_purple));
                break;

            case R.color.red:
                holder.mColorImageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_red));
                break;

            case R.color.pink:
                holder.mColorImageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_pink));
                break;

            case R.color.skyblue:
                holder.mColorImageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_skyblue));
                break;

            case R.color.brown:
                holder.mColorImageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_brown));
                break;

            case R.color.green:
                holder.mColorImageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_green));
                break;
        }

        holder.mColorImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(mOnColorSelected != null)
                    mOnColorSelected.onColorSelected(v, p, color);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return COUNT;
    }

    public void setOnColorSelected(OnColorSelected i)
    {
        mOnColorSelected = i;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageButton mColorImageButton;

        public ViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);

            mColorImageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton_color_note);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my layout_popup_menu_note_color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_popup_menu_note_color"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the link I checked, none of them worked for me. Except for reflection hack, since I haven't tried it.

[PopupWindow in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944987/popupwindow-in-android)

[Set own layout in popup window in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153651/set-own-layout-in-popup-window-in-android)

[How to define layout in a PopupWindow from an xml file, when `PopupWindow` method is called from a separate class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409781/how-to-define-layout-in-a-popupwindow-from-an-xml-file-when-popupwindow-method)

`PopupMenu` works for me but I wanted icons. I know for the fact that is not possible.  But I beg to differ, a lot of apps I saw has a button somewhere on their layout, I clicked it and then a `PopupWindow` will appear, making the button look like a menu dropdown list.

The reason I am doing this because as you can see, my bottom panel menu is a just a custom layout. I created a custom labeled button, and I want a menu to popup when I clicked it.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Neon, could you please post the xml of recyclerview_popup_menu_note_color?

Comment: @KarenForde Hi Karen, please see my edit, the name of the file is `layout_popup_menu_note_color`. This is where `recyclerview_popup_menu_note_color located`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for posting the xml. Please see my suggested answer below and let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem you are seeing is because you have set the RelativeLayout of your PopupWindow to:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

This is why your icons are appearing stretched out over the entire view so it doesn't really look like a popup.

Try changing to the following to see if it helps:

```
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. I think my approach is incompatible with each other. It doesn't behave quite so like a menu. I think I am going to throw this idea and stick to dialogs instead.

Comment: @Neon - Sorry, it's difficult to visualise exactly what you're trying to achieve. It looked like you wanted the colour squares to appear on a popup window (which I think is the white square in the middle of your image. It looked like the colour layout was filling the whole screen, so I figured moving to wrap_content would at least bring you closer to what you're trying to achieve. If you want to create an image that shows exactly what you want it to look like, and another of how it looks with wrap_content, I'd be happy to try run your code in sample project and see if I can fix it up for you.

Comment: Hi @KarenForde sorry for the late reply, please see my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @NeonWarge Trying to run your code with some values subbed in where code is missing above, but I'm getting android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager for the line  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_popup_menu_note_color , null);  Could you post full xml or code that is preventing that for you? And also the layout that contains imagebutton_color_note. Thanks!

Comment: Also to give you another cue, I tried running the same thing using dialog. Guess what, same behavior, it looks like RecyclerView is not "Wrapping" its height and width will stretch as the screen size.

Comment: I updated my dependencies to 23.4.0 and it fixes the problem didn't even finch the code a bit. Also, it lead me to believe that I must be using GridView instead. Thank you!

Comment: @NeonWarge Sorry for the late reply - great to hear your problem got fixed :)